# I want to send notification according to Eastern Time Zone using OneSignal Server REST API in java

Tags: java, android, json, notifications, onesignal

using the following code :

```
String strJsonBody = 
{
    "\"send_after\": \"2018-03-27 02:06:00 GMT-0400\""  

}
```

using the above code i am able to receive the notification according to Indian Standard Time, does the above code specially send_after parameter will i able to send notification according to Eastern Time zone.

I want to send notification to New York,  i want to confirm the new york time zone is it GMT-04:00 or GMT-05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"\"send_after\": \"2018-03-27 02:06:00 GMT-0400\""
```

works and notification sent successfully to New York. New York time zone is GMT-04:00